# How to pass a variable to a stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transaction

Calling the following procedure in DO $$ bloc seems to not work correctly .

Procedure :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pLog(P_VAR_LOG text)  
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF D_SetLog THEN


      RAISE NOTICE '[LOG %] %',to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY - HH24:MI:SS'),P_VAR_LOG;


  END IF
;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried to declare the PROCEDURE in the declare bloc but it's not working.

Here is the DO $$ bloc definition :

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE

CRITERE1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
            DOSSIER.ID_DOSSIER,
            DOSSIER.ED_ETAT
    FROM
        IMM_DOSSIER DOSSIER,
        IMM_CHANTIER CHANTIER
    WHERE
        DOSSIER.ID_DOSSIER = CHANTIER.ID_DOSSIER
        AND DOSSIER.ED_ETAT <> 'CLOS'
        AND CHANTIER.DATE_FIN_REELLE is null
        AND CHANTIER.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE is not null
        AND CHANTIER.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE < LOCALTIMESTAMP

UNION

    SELECT
            DOSSIER.ID_DOSSIER,
            DOSSIER.ED_ETAT
    FROM (
            SELECT
                DEVIS.ID_DOSSIER,
                MIN(TRAVAUX.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE) DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE
            FROM
                IMM_DEVIS DEVIS, IMM_TRAVAUX_DEVIS TRAVAUX
            WHERE
              DEVIS.ID_DEVIS = TRAVAUX.ID_DEVIS
              AND TRAVAUX.DATE_FIN_REELLE is null
              AND TRAVAUX.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE is not null
            GROUP BY DEVIS.ID_DOSSIER
        )
        DOSSIER_CIBLE,
        IMM_DOSSIER DOSSIER
    WHERE
        DOSSIER.ID_DOSSIER = DOSSIER_CIBLE.ID_DOSSIER
        AND DOSSIER.ED_ETAT <> 'CLOS'
        and DOSSIER_CIBLE.DATE_FIN_SOUHAITEE < LOCALTIMESTAMP;

-- Def des enregistrements pour les curseurs
V_C_CRITERE1 RECORD;

V_INSERT INTEGER := 0;

D_CodeRet INTEGER;

D_SetLog    BOOLEAN;

/*****************************************************************************
**  NOM MNEMONIQUE  : pLog
*****************************************************************************/



/*****************************************************************************
**  MAIN
*****************************************************************************/
BEGIN



    D_SetLog    := TRUE
;


    CALL pLog('Suppression des anciennes alertes : ')
; 
END $$;
```

When i execute this sql script i get the following :

```
SET
DROP SEQUENCE
WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT
CREATE SEQUENCE
WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT
CREATE PROCEDURE
DO
```

The **NOTICE** is not being displayed and can't figure out why.

Comment: It is working correctly, only it will not do what you think it should.

Comment: So what can i change so that the NOTICE can be displayed in terminal ?

Comment: You need to pass `D_SetLog` as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no global variables in PostgreSQL, sou you'd have to pass `d_setlog` as parameter to the procedure.

An alternative is to use a custom placeholder parameter in PostgreSQL:

The calling function does

```
SET mylog.active = true;
```

and the called procedure tests

```
IF current_setting('mylog.active', TRUE) = 'true' THEN ...
```

Note that such parameters are always strings.